# Finding out exact unit of measurement of organic carbon density map on soil grids system

Tags: soilgrids

The soilgrids site at https://soilgrids.org/ has an interactive map.

When I click on the Organic carbon density map with the computer mouse a message pops up with data with units of measurement in hg/dm3, and in the legend to the map other units of measurement are g/dm3.

Here is a screenshot, you can see hg/dm3 in one place and g/dm3 in two places.

[image]

What units of measurement are considered correct? The "Properties" section of this page https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids has some information on scaling units.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. It is preferred to ask GIS related problems software or programming in this platform. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to ask questions. You can try asking in [Earth Data Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is the "*Organic carbon density map*"? Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/460534/edit) to clarify.

Comment: I've improved this Q for you (which might get it re-opened) by adding a screenshot and a link. I'm assuming this clarifies your Q, if not then edit the Q yourself.